# Add Product Quantity in Magento Order Item in Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I want to show product quantity in Magento 1.9.x order items in admin panel. I'm not talking about quantity ordered, but product quantity itself.
Is there a way to check product qty in sales order item in Magento admin panel? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
Below is the code I added to **name.phtml** located in **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items** and it gets product stock quantity in sales order items:

```
 $_sku = $_item->getSku();
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_sku);
 $stock_count = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); echo $stock_count;
```

Regards